# Error:Execution failed for task ':dexRelease'

Tags: android

This is my .gradle file:

```js
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "net.test.android.sk"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4-22.2.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-support-v7-recyclerview-22.2.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/applovin-6.1.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/appodeal-1.14.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/chartboost-6.2.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/flurry-analytics-6.2.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/unity-ads-1.4.7.jar')
    compile files('libs/inmobi-5.2.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/my-target-4.2.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/yandex-metrica-2.30.jar')
}
```

When I build my Android app, I get the next error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':dexRelease'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Install multidex but new error: Error:Execution failed for task ':packageAllReleaseClassesForMultiDex'. > java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.class

Comment: You're using quite a few libraries, including all of the play services. Your app might have reached the 65k methods count limit. Have you tried using multidex support ? http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: You really need the full play-service? if not you could just reference a isolated module. For instance, if you were using just gcm: 

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'